# Ajax setInterval causing browser to be unresponsive

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ajax - one variable test</title>
 <style>
   body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;}
 </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id="variable1"><var1></ol>

<script>
setInterval(function()
 {
  $("#variable1").load("ajax_v00.html")
 },3000);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am using an embedded web-server that reports a status to var1.

example:  Ok or Head Up

The above is crashing any browser that I tested on.  Can someone see if I am doing something
wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes,  you're sending an ajax request in a setInterval. that's wrong because you have no idea how long that ajax request is going to take to complete. It could take 1ms, or it could take 15 seconds.

Comment: Why just call the ajax or you can use a callback function after that. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How do I implement a callback function/Ajax? If I place a callback function will it report that request?

Comment: Why you need to load page every 3 seconds?

Comment: The embedded unit will update the variables say every 10ms, so I just figured the user can have an update to that information in about 3 seconds, I would rather have the user get that information once a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request might take more than 3 seconds to execute thus stacking the requests until the browser cannot handle it all and crash... Instead of using an interval, you should use a timeout that will execute the request 3 seconds AFTER the last one finished. Here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ajax - one variable test</title>
 <style>
   body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;}
 </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id="variable1"><var1></ol>

<script>
function doRefresh()
 {
  $.ajax({
     url:"ajax_v00.html",
     success:function(data){
         $("#variable1").html(data);
         setTimeout(doRefresh,3000);
     }
  });
}
setTimeout(doRefresh,3000);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above in Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error? What is data? Is data var1?

Comment: setTimeout(doRefresh,3000); }});

Comment: Even though I found the syntax error, the problem still exists. I don't know if I am suppose to replace data/w something?

Comment: I am very sorry, bad indentation made me forget to close some brackets. Data is simply a variable that contains the html (resonse) received from the ajax, you can read about jQuery ajax at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ see the success part in the parameter